# Extrair conteúdo de <script>

Tags: php

Como posso estar extraindo o valor de "csrf_token" deste código na página:

**EDIT:** Estava faltando uma `}` no final da `string` da váriavel `window._sharedData`, dessa forma a string json ficava inválida.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":null,"config":{"csrf_token":"WrNBfRGzWkUl4tsZsqm1HfwhDUDKNFts","viewer":null},"supports_es6":true,"country_code":"unknown","language_code":"pt-br","locale":"pt_BR","entry_data":{"LoginAndSignupPage":[{"captcha":{"enabled":false,"key":""},"gdpr_required":false,"tos_version":"row","username_hint":""}]},"gatekeepers":{"ld":true,"seo":true,"seoht":true,"sf":true,"saa":true},"knobs":{"acct:ntb":0,"cb":0,"captcha":0}}
```

Tentei desta forma, mas não obtive exito:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
          $json = json_decode($data, true);
          echo  $json["config"][0]["csrf_token"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// passando o json diretamente para poder testar
$data = '{"activity_counts":null,"config":{"csrf_token":"WrNBfRGzWkUl4tsZsqm1HfwhDUDKNFts","viewer":null},"supports_es6":true,"country_code":"unknown","language_code":"pt-br","locale":"pt_BR","entry_data":{"LoginAndSignupPage":[{"captcha":{"enabled":false,"key":""},"gdpr_required":false,"tos_version":"row","username_hint":""}]},"gatekeepers":{"ld":true,"seo":true,"seoht":true,"sf":true,"saa":true},"knobs":{"acct:ntb":0,"cb":0,"captcha":0}}';

$json = json_decode($data); // transformando string json em objeto

// acessando atributo da chave desejada
var_dump($json->{'config'}->{'csrf_token'});
?>
```

Espero ter lhe ajudado.